# Visual Studio 2008 WriteFile

Tags: c++, windows-ce

Im using VS2008 for compiling and developing my application. Im required to take Adc input and serial print it through RS232 in a WinCE6 OS over some termianl like putty or hyperterminal. The problem is when I use the WriteFile function it gives me the following error.

```
 Error  3   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'double' to 'char [32]'  c:\Users\Sohan\Downloads\uartdemo\uartdemo\src\main.c   137 Sohan_1
```

I want to take the input from ADC channel and then after converting it to voltage i have to transmitt. I have tried using a constant char string and it works but when i take the input from the channel and then try it doesnt work.

```
HANDLE portHandle;
DWORD noOfBytesRead = 0;
DWORD bytesTransmitted = 0;   
DWORD firstChoice = 0;
BOOL retVal = FALSE;
char c="hello";

char transmit2Buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = "7.8888v";

char volt[BUFFER_SIZE];
WriteFile(portHandle, transmit2Buffer, strlen(transmit2Buffer), &bytesTransmitted, NULL);

WriteFile(portHandle, volt, strlen(volt), &bytesTransmitted, NULL);
```

the first write function works but the second doesnt. variable volt will keep on changing so how should i write it.please help..

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Answer (score 0):

After searching i have got an answer for my question.
this worked for me..
You can use sprintf() as you have done to convert a double to a string, but I would actually recommend using _snprintf() instead simply because sprintf() has no regard for the fact that strings are fixed length devices in memory and will overflow if you don't watch it. _snprintf() allows you to specify the length of the out string, just be sure to specify the size as one less than the actual allocated memory block, because _snprintf() does not store the terminating null character if it has to cut the output short.

An example us using _snprintf() is:

```
void ToString(char * outStr, int length, double val)

{

_snprintf(outStr,length,"%f",val);

}
```

Got this answer on some website!!!